# Change the home page of a wiki library

Tags: powershell, wiki-pages, sharepoint-designer

I saved an old wiki library as a template w/ content and then created a wiki library from that template. The new wiki, however, shows all the wiki pages in a list of files because the new wiki home page URL is "/Forms/AllPages.aspx" instead of the normal default "home.aspx".

The "home.aspx" page is in the list of the wiki pages and I want to make it the default home page for my wiki like it would be if I made a wiki from scratch. Is this possible to change?

I've tried opening the site in SP Designer, selecting "home.aspx", and setting it as the home page. This set's my top-level site's homepage, though, which is not what I want.

Additional Details:
Using SP Online for new location, the old library was on-premise SP2010.

Comment: Shot in the dark here as I don't have SP Online: Open the page in a web browser, click on the _Page_ tab, then click _Make Homepage_ in the _Page Actions_ section.

Comment: This only changes the home page of the site the wiki library lives in.

Comment: Create a redirect page as your homepage and redirect it to your wiki page. Pretty sure you can't set a page from a different site as the homepage of another site

Comment: Can you elaborate on this Roland? I'm not trying to set a page from a different site as the home page of another site. I copied an existing wiki as a template and then created a new one using that template. However, instead of the wiki using the "home.aspx" page as it's default page, it's using "/forms/allpages.aspx. If you create a new wiki, it's default is "home.aspx", so really all I'm trying to do is set it up like a default wiki would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using CSOM. The sample code below works on a Wiki Page Library created in Office 365:

```
# Enter your credentials and the site URL here
$username = "user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"  
$password = "Pass@word"  
$url = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeamSite"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force  

# The path here may need to change
# Copy the SP2013 DLLs into a suitable location such as c:\Lib
Add-Type -Path "C:\Lib\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Lib\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object... 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)  
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)  
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials  

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)  
{  
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: $Url"  
}  

# Grab the root web context
$rootWeb = $clientContext.Web 
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb) 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery() 

# Grab the lists
$lists = $rootWeb.Lists
$clientContext.Load($lists) 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Find the correct list. Enter the title of your list.
$list = $clientContext.Web.Lists | where {$_.Title -eq "Wiki"}
$clientContext.Load($list) 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

# Set the root folder welcome page to the correct value and update
$list.RootFolder.WelcomePage="Home.aspx"
$list.RootFolder.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Andy, I keep getting an error after trying to run "$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()" after loading $rootWeb. It states "exception calling "executequery" with "0" arguments: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.". Any ideas?

Comment: It appears my credentials were failing. Nevermind Andy!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!