# How to set to show a page contents instead of All Pages in Wiki?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, wiki, default

When I click on *Team Wiki - Wiki Page Library -* from navigator I want it to show a page `Home.aspx` instead of showing *All Pages*, I can only set a page as *Home Page* not able to set it as default page of my wiki - Team wiki -.

I'm using SharePoint Server 2013.
For example I want its *Web Address* instead of `http://sharpointserver/Team%20Wiki/Forms/AllPages.aspx` to be `http://sharpointserver/Team%20Wiki/Home.aspx`, But it is read-only in its related `listedit.aspx` or in *Team Wiki > Settings*.

Thanks for help.

Comment: please add an example for the current URL and the required URL

Comment: @M.Qassas Thanks for attention, I update the question ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not see "Navigation" section, you can copy `_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` after your site link like this:

```
http://<Site>/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx
```

and in this section

> **Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting**
>   Use this section to reorder and modify the navigation items under this site. You can create, delete and edit navigation links and headings. You can also move navigation items under headings and choose to display or hide pages and subsites.

Then, edit URL of link navigation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found that by replacing `settings.aspx`  to `AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`  I can reach to `Navigation Settings`, that does the trick for me - By editing URL part ;).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this as well - a link to a wiki on the left navigation that is `https://<site>/<LibraryName>` without the closing `/`  will show the home page in one library, but go to AllPages.aspx for another.

The only thing I've been able to determine is you have to have a `Home.aspx` page to do that. Since yours is called `wikihome.aspx` it won't work.

If that doesn't work, you might have to resort to code or Powershell. I found this [Change the home page of a wiki library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173333/change-the-home-page-of-a-wiki-library) that shows you have to set the Welcome Page property:

```
$list.RootFolder.WelcomePage="Home.aspx"
$list.RootFolder.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Checked with `Home.aspx` and doesn't work either!?

Comment: Bummer. I updated my answer with some other examples - it looks like you might have to code it in csom or powershell. As to why the WelcomePage definition gets unhooked I do not know.

Comment: Thank for updates and finding that related question-answer, I hope someone gives me a way without coding, I'll try it soon ;).